# Convert PHP script in Powershell script

Tags: php, powershell

I have to convert a PHP script in Powershell script.

I have current PHP script:

```
<?php
// read text file
$File = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$typePers = array("Personale Viaggiante","Personale Interno");
$excludeFields = array("IT0006","IT0017","IT0077","Personale Viaggiante","Personale Interno","IT0105");
$emptyValue = "NaN";
$rowfinal = "";
// Output one line until end-of-file
while(!feof($File)) {
    $row = explode(";",fgets($File));
    $substring = "IT0006;IT0017;";
// left string
    $lstr = "";
// right string
    $rstr = "";
    $type = array_intersect($row, $typePers);
    $keys = array_keys($type);
    if($keys == null) $type = $emptyValue;
    else $type = $row[$keys[0]];
    $j = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<count($row); $i++){
        if(in_array($row[$i],$excludeFields)){
            unset($row[$i]);
            $j++;
        }
    }
    for($i=0; $i<22;$i++)$lstr .= $row[$i].";";
    foreach($row as $k => $v)
        if($k > 22)if(!empty($v))$rstr .= $v.";";

    $rstr = substr($rstr,0,-1);
    $substring .= $type;
    $substring .= ";IT0077;NaN;IT0105;";
    $rowfinal .= $lstr.$substring.$rstr;
}
$file = 'test.txt';
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $rowfinal);
fclose($sapFile);
?>
```

I started writing this script in Powershell, but it is incomplete.

```
$File = Get-Content "file.txt"
$FilePath = "dump.txt"

$typePers = @("Personale Viaggiante","Personale Interno")
$excludeFields = @("IT0006","IT0017","IT0077","Personale Viaggiante","IT0105","Personale Interno")
$emptyValue = "NaN"
$rowfinal = ""

foreach($line in $File) {
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$row = $line -split ";"
    $substring = "IT0006;IT0017;"
    $lstr = ""
    $rstr = ""

    $ityp = -1;
    for($i=0; $i -lt $row.Count; $i++){
        if($typePers -contains $row[$i] ){
            $ityp = $i
        }
    }
    if($ityp -eq "-1"){
        $type = "NaN"
    }else{
        $type = $row[$ityp]
    }

    $j = 0;
    for($i=0; $i -lt $row.Count; $i++){
        if($excludeFields -contains $row[$i]){
            $row.RemoveAt($i)
            $j++;
        }
    }

    for($i=0; $i -lt 22;$i++) {
        $lstr += $row[$i]+";"
    }


    $k = 0;
    ForEach($v in $row) {
        if($k -gt 22) {
            if($v -ne ""){
                $rstr += $v+";"
            }
        }
        $k++
    }

    $rstr = $rstr.Substring(0,$rstr.Length-1)
    $substring += $type
    $substring += ";IT0077;NaN;IT0105;";
    $rowfinal += $lstr+$substring+$rstr+"`r`n"
}

$rowfinal | Out-File -FilePath $FilePath
```

I have only problem with Remove method.
When I have IT0006 value in array, I have IT0105 duplicated...

To end, I have to add header columns for CSV file.
For example, I would to define an array with header:

```
$header = @('column1','column2',...,'column_n');
```

and add header at the file to export in CSV.

Comment: It might be easier to do a rewrite instead of conversion. Can you edit the question and explain what the transformation is supposed do? Add a sample input and desired output too.

Comment: I completely agree with @vonPryz, don't try to translate PHP to PowerShell statement by statement